# C# Entity Framework : stored procedure returning null value temporarily

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

We are trying to use an entity to write to our database via a stored procedure and it is working, however, the stored procedure also has an output to return the ID of the row it just inserted. I left out the initializing of all the passed values but our problem lies within the following code:

```
 ObjectParameter output = new ObjectParameter("cUSTOMER_ID", typeof(int));
 var test = database.ADD_CUSTOMER_JSON(companyID, customerName, firstName, lastName, address_1, address_2, cityID, stateID, zipID, primaryPhoneNumber, alternatePhoneNumber, secondaryPhoneNumber, emailAddress, customerNotes, modifiedBy, output);

 if(QuickBooksController.getTokens(companyID).Length > 0)
 {
      QuickBookCustomerQuery customer = GetCustomerDetailsForQuickBooks((int)output.Value);
      QuickBooksController.CreateCustomer(companyID, customer, (int)output.Value);
 }
```

When we run this code, we get an error that `output.value` is null:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
>   System.Data.Entity.CoreObjects.ObjectParameter.Value.get returned null

We have a breakpoint there and if we check the value of `output` we see it as null however if we wait a few seconds and check it then it has the value and the data does the write to the database. If we continue code execution after that then it works. I would think that the code inside of the `If` is blocked until the SP finishes and returns its value. We use this exact same code elsewhere in the application without a problem. The only difference is what happens after the `var test = ...` Any suggestions or ideas? We are all stumped on this.

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ADD_CUSTOMER_JSON]
    @COMPANY_ID INT,
    @CUSTOMER_NAME NVARCHAR(50) = '',
    @FIRST_NAME NVARCHAR(50) = '',
    @LAST_NAME NVARCHAR(50) = '',
    @ADDRESS_1 NVARCHAR(100) = '',
    @ADDRESS_2 NVARCHAR(100) = '',
    @CITY_ID INT,
    @STATE_ID INT,
    @ZIP_CODE_ID INT,
    @PRIMARY_PHONE_NUMBER NVARCHAR(50) = '',
    @ALTERNATE_PHONE_NUMBER NVARCHAR(50) = '',
    @SECONDARY_PHONE_NUMBER NVARCHAR(50) = '', 
    @EMAIL_ADDRESS NVARCHAR(100) = '',
    @CUSTOMER_NOTES NVARCHAR(2500) = '',
    @MODIFIED_BY NVARCHAR(50),

    @CUSTOMER_ID INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @CUSTOMER_BIRTHDATE DATE,
            @DEFAULT_PERSON_NOTE NVARCHAR(50),
            @CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ID INT,
            @CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_NOTES_ID INT,
            @CUSTOMER_NOTES_ID INT = '',
            @CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_NOTES NVARCHAR(2500) = '',
            -- @CUSTOMER_NOTES NVARCHAR(2500) = '',
            @CUSTOMER_PERSON_NOTE_ID INT,
            @CUSTOMER_PERSON_ID INT

    IF (@CUSTOMER_NAME = '')
    BEGIN
        SET @CUSTOMER_NAME = @LAST_NAME + ', ' + @FIRST_NAME
    END

    SET @CUSTOMER_BIRTHDATE = CONVERT(DATE, '1/1/1975')
    SET @DEFAULT_PERSON_NOTE = 'PRIMARY CONTACT FOR ' + CAST(@CUSTOMER_NAME AS VARCHAR(50)) + '.'

    EXEC DBO.GET_ADDRESS_ID_BY_ADDRESS_CITY_ID_STATE_ID_ZIP_CODE_ID
        @ADDRESS_1 = @ADDRESS_1,
        @ADDRESS_2 = @ADDRESS_2,
        @CITY_ID = @CITY_ID,
        @STATE_ID = @STATE_ID,
        @ZIP_CODE_ID = @ZIP_CODE_ID,
        @ADDRESS_ID = @CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ID OUTPUT

    IF (ISNULL (@CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ID, 0) = 0)
    BEGIN
        EXEC    [DBO].[ADD_ADDRESS]
                @NOTES_ID = @CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_NOTES_ID,
                @ADDRESS_1 = @ADDRESS_1,
                @ADDRESS_2 = @ADDRESS_2,
                @CROSS_STREET = '',
                @CITY_ID = @CITY_ID, 
                @STATE_ID = @STATE_ID,
                @ZIP_CODE_ID = @ZIP_CODE_ID,
                @MODIFIED_BY = @MODIFIED_BY,
                @ADDRESS_ID = @CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ID OUTPUT
    END

    EXEC    [DBO].[ADD_NOTES]
            @NOTES = @CUSTOMER_NOTES,
            @MODIFIED_BY = @MODIFIED_BY,
            @NOTES_ID = @CUSTOMER_NOTES_ID OUTPUT    

    EXEC    [DBO].[ADD_NOTES]
            @NOTES = @CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_NOTES,
            @MODIFIED_BY = @MODIFIED_BY,
            @NOTES_ID = @CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_NOTES_ID OUTPUT    

    EXEC    [DBO].[ADD_NOTES]
            @NOTES = @DEFAULT_PERSON_NOTE,
            @MODIFIED_BY = @MODIFIED_BY,
            @NOTES_ID = @CUSTOMER_PERSON_NOTE_ID OUTPUT    

    EXEC    [DBO].[ADD_PERSON]
            @FIRST_NAME = @FIRST_NAME,
            @LAST_NAME = @LAST_NAME,
            @NOTE_ID = @CUSTOMER_PERSON_NOTE_ID,
            @DATE_OF_BIRTH = @CUSTOMER_BIRTHDATE,
            @PREFIX_ID = 0,
            @SUFFIX_ID = 0,
            @PRIMARY_PHONE = @PRIMARY_PHONE_NUMBER,
            @PRIMARY_PHONE_EXT = '',
            @ALTERNATE_PHONE = @ALTERNATE_PHONE_NUMBER,
            @ALTERNATE_PHONE_EXT = '',
            @CELL_PHONE = @SECONDARY_PHONE_NUMBER,
            @MOBILE_PROVIDER_ID = NULL,
            @FAX_NUMBER = '',
            @EMAIL = @EMAIL_ADDRESS,
            @MODIFIED_BY = @MODIFIED_BY,
            @PERSON_ID = @CUSTOMER_PERSON_ID OUTPUT

    INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (COMPANY_ID,
            QUICK_BOOKS_REFERENCE_NUMBER,
            QUICK_BOOKS_LIST_ID,
            QUICK_BOOKS_EDIT_SEQUENCE,
            CUSTOMER_NAME,
            DATE_REGISTERED,
            NOTES_ID,
            PAYCODE_ID,
            PRIMARY_CONTACT_ID,
            BILLING_ADDRESS_ID,
            CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID,
            CUSTOMER_FLAG_ID,
            DEMOGRAPHICS_DESCRIPTOR,
            IS_ACTIVE,
            MODIFIED_BY)
    VALUES (@COMPANY_ID,
            0,
            0,
            '0',
            @CUSTOMER_NAME,
            GETDATE(),
            @CUSTOMER_NOTES_ID,
            1,
            @CUSTOMER_PERSON_ID,
            @CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ID,
            1,
            1,
            NULL,
            1,
            @MODIFIED_BY)

    SELECT @CUSTOMER_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES (CUSTOMER_ID,
           ADDRESS_ID,
           ADDRESS_TYPE_ID,
           FROM_DATE,
           MODIFIED_BY)
    VALUES (@CUSTOMER_ID,
            @CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ID,
            2,
            GETDATE(),
            @MODIFIED_BY)

    SELECT CUSTOMER_ID 
    FROM CUSTOMERS 
    WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = @CUSTOMER_ID;
END
```

Full function

```
public ObjectResult<Nullable<int>> CreateCustomer([FromBody]dynamic customerInput)
{
    var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
    var claimRole = identity.Claims.ToList()[0].Value.ToInt();
    var claimCompany = identity.Claims.ToList()[3].Value.ToInt();
    var claimUsername = identity.Claims.ToList()[5].Value.ToString();
    int[] allowedRoles = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 , 8};

    if (Array.IndexOf(allowedRoles, claimRole) != -1)
    {
        if (claimRole == 3 && claimCompany != (int)customerInput["COMPANY_ID"])
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
        }

        var companyID = (int)customerInput["COMPANY_ID"];
        var customerName = customerInput["CUSTOMER_NAME"].ToString();
        var firstName = customerInput["FIRST_NAME"].ToString();
        var lastName = customerInput["LAST_NAME"].ToString();
        var address_1 = customerInput["ADDRESS_1"].ToString();
        var address_2 = customerInput["ADDRESS_2"].ToString();
        var cityID = (int)customerInput["CITY_ID"];
        var stateID = (int)customerInput["STATE_ID"];
        var zipID = (int)customerInput["ZIP_CODE_ID"];
        var primaryPhoneNumber = customerInput["PRIMARY_PHONE_NUMBER"].ToString();
        var alternatePhoneNumber = customerInput["ALTERNATE_PHONE_NUMBER"].ToString();
        var secondaryPhoneNumber = customerInput["SECONDARY_PHONE_NUMBER"].ToString();
        var emailAddress = customerInput["EMAIL_ADDRESS"].ToString();
        var customerNotes = customerInput["CUSTOMER_NOTES"].ToString();
        var modifiedBy = claimUsername;

        ObjectParameter output = new ObjectParameter("cUSTOMER_ID", typeof(int));

        var test = database.ADD_CUSTOMER_JSON(companyID, customerName, firstName, lastName, address_1, address_2, cityID, stateID, zipID, primaryPhoneNumber, alternatePhoneNumber, secondaryPhoneNumber, emailAddress, customerNotes, modifiedBy, output);

        if(QuickBooksController.getTokens(companyID).Length > 0)
        {
            // Do the quickbooks call to create the customer and update the DB with the quickbooks id
            QuickBookCustomerQuery customer = GetCustomerDetailsForQuickBooks((int)output.Value);
            QuickBooksController.CreateCustomer(companyID, customer, (int)output.Value);
        }        

        return test;
    }

    throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
}
```

ADD_CUSTOMER_JSON Entity Code:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<Nullable<int>> ADD_CUSTOMER_JSON(Nullable<int> cOMPANY_ID, string cUSTOMER_NAME, string fIRST_NAME, string lAST_NAME, string aDDRESS_1, string aDDRESS_2, Nullable<int> cITY_ID, Nullable<int> sTATE_ID, Nullable<int> zIP_CODE_ID, string pRIMARY_PHONE_NUMBER, string aLTERNATE_PHONE_NUMBER, string sECONDARY_PHONE_NUMBER, string eMAIL_ADDRESS, string cUSTOMER_NOTES, string mODIFIED_BY, ObjectParameter cUSTOMER_ID)
{
    var cOMPANY_IDParameter = cOMPANY_ID.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("COMPANY_ID", cOMPANY_ID) :
        new ObjectParameter("COMPANY_ID", typeof(int));

    var cUSTOMER_NAMEParameter = cUSTOMER_NAME != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("CUSTOMER_NAME", cUSTOMER_NAME) :
        new ObjectParameter("CUSTOMER_NAME", typeof(string));

    var fIRST_NAMEParameter = fIRST_NAME != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("FIRST_NAME", fIRST_NAME) :
        new ObjectParameter("FIRST_NAME", typeof(string));

    var lAST_NAMEParameter = lAST_NAME != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("LAST_NAME", lAST_NAME) :
        new ObjectParameter("LAST_NAME", typeof(string));

    var aDDRESS_1Parameter = aDDRESS_1 != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("ADDRESS_1", aDDRESS_1) :
        new ObjectParameter("ADDRESS_1", typeof(string));

    var aDDRESS_2Parameter = aDDRESS_2 != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("ADDRESS_2", aDDRESS_2) :
        new ObjectParameter("ADDRESS_2", typeof(string));

    var cITY_IDParameter = cITY_ID.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("CITY_ID", cITY_ID) :
        new ObjectParameter("CITY_ID", typeof(int));

    var sTATE_IDParameter = sTATE_ID.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("STATE_ID", sTATE_ID) :
        new ObjectParameter("STATE_ID", typeof(int));

    var zIP_CODE_IDParameter = zIP_CODE_ID.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("ZIP_CODE_ID", zIP_CODE_ID) :
        new ObjectParameter("ZIP_CODE_ID", typeof(int));

    var pRIMARY_PHONE_NUMBERParameter = pRIMARY_PHONE_NUMBER != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("PRIMARY_PHONE_NUMBER", pRIMARY_PHONE_NUMBER) :
        new ObjectParameter("PRIMARY_PHONE_NUMBER", typeof(string));

    var aLTERNATE_PHONE_NUMBERParameter = aLTERNATE_PHONE_NUMBER != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("ALTERNATE_PHONE_NUMBER", aLTERNATE_PHONE_NUMBER) :
        new ObjectParameter("ALTERNATE_PHONE_NUMBER", typeof(string));

    var sECONDARY_PHONE_NUMBERParameter = sECONDARY_PHONE_NUMBER != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("SECONDARY_PHONE_NUMBER", sECONDARY_PHONE_NUMBER) :
        new ObjectParameter("SECONDARY_PHONE_NUMBER", typeof(string));

    var eMAIL_ADDRESSParameter = eMAIL_ADDRESS != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("EMAIL_ADDRESS", eMAIL_ADDRESS) :
        new ObjectParameter("EMAIL_ADDRESS", typeof(string));

    var cUSTOMER_NOTESParameter = cUSTOMER_NOTES != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("CUSTOMER_NOTES", cUSTOMER_NOTES) :
        new ObjectParameter("CUSTOMER_NOTES", typeof(string));

    var mODIFIED_BYParameter = mODIFIED_BY != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("MODIFIED_BY", mODIFIED_BY) :
        new ObjectParameter("MODIFIED_BY", typeof(string));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Nullable<int>>("ADD_CUSTOMER_JSON", cOMPANY_IDParameter, cUSTOMER_NAMEParameter, fIRST_NAMEParameter, lAST_NAMEParameter, aDDRESS_1Parameter, aDDRESS_2Parameter, cITY_IDParameter, sTATE_IDParameter, zIP_CODE_IDParameter, pRIMARY_PHONE_NUMBERParameter, aLTERNATE_PHONE_NUMBERParameter, sECONDARY_PHONE_NUMBERParameter, eMAIL_ADDRESSParameter, cUSTOMER_NOTESParameter, mODIFIED_BYParameter, cUSTOMER_ID);
}
```

Comment: We'll need to see the stored proc. And a [mcve].

Comment: So the only asynchronous functions we call are in the if so shouldn't it wait to call those until after the procedure execution? Aside from that, we do not have any async functions being used in this function.

Comment: I added the full function and the stored procedure being used. Unforatnely the SP is legacy so it's a bit hard on the eyes.

Comment: I think the code of interest is going to be `ADD_CUSTOMER_JSON` because that is what is acting in an async manner if output is not initially set.

Comment: That is what it looks like to me but should it be running asynchronously without us asking it to do so?

Comment: Which code would you like? Right now our service from the angular application calls this endpoint which then calls the SP and the additional code inside the IF.

Comment: Are you saying the `ADD_CUSTOMER_JSON` "function" because that is the stored procedure we are calling.

Comment: I'm saying `ADD_CUSTOMER_JSON` because that is where the `output` parameter should be populated (I think?). And if its not populated when you break on the line directly following, then the something within `ADD_CUSTOMER_JSON` must be running async.

Comment: Again, that is what I feel like it happens to but I can't wrap my head around why that would be happening. It is auto-generated code from Entity when we "imported" the SP, I can attach that code if you'd like but from reading it nothing leads me to believe it should act asynchronously.

Comment: Please show us `QuickBooksController.CreateCustomer`.

Comment: "I can't wrap my head around why that would be happening" - indeed, but I can't see any other explanation from the code you have posted.

Comment: Aside: In what way is `SELECT CUSTOMER_ID FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = @CUSTOMER_ID;` more suitable than `SELECT @CUSTOMER_ID as CUSTOMER_ID;`?

Comment: This is why it is so frustrating, I added the code for that entity created for `ADD_CUSTOMER_JSON` but I don't think it adds anything to the equation, unfortunately.

Comment: @mjwills I can show that function but will it help if it doesn't even make it there without erroring?

Comment: The issue here is that you haven't provided a [mcve]. If you provided a [mcve] then I wouldn't need to ask to see details that you think are irrelevant. Since by creating the [mcve] you would have already ruled them out. ;P

Comment: @HABO Again, the SP is legacy code that we inherited and we are working to fix when we can but we are trying to get this working for the time.

Comment: @mjwills As far as what `Test` is, it shows as a nullable int.

Comment: @mjwills Also I am trying to find a minimal reproducible example but this code works elsewhere which is what is odd, only in this very instance do we get this behavior. Calling near-identical code with the only thing different is what comes after the SP is called however in this instance we get the aforementioned error inside the if. We believed that the call to the SP is blocking and so we shouldn't even realistically hit that code until we get the result back from the Database. Apparently, somehow we are flawed in this thinking but we can't seem to find out why and how to amend the issue.

Comment: From a quick google it looked like there have been the odd issue with returning parameters from EF... as a workaround you might try a different method e.g. select the new id instead of suing a parameter.

Comment: Have you used SQL Profiler or some other method to capture the SQL actually generated by your method? I don't think it works like `SqlParameter.Direction` does in ADO.NET.